ImportError: cannot import name 'Gemini' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)
This is the code

!pip install google-generativeai
!pip install llama-index-llms-gemini
!pip install llama-index llama-index-llms-gemini

from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, StorageContext
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.llms import Gemini 

And this is the problem
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4f0ccebf76ca> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, StorageContext
      2 from llama_index.core import Settings
----> 3 from llama_index.llms import Gemini

ImportError: cannot import name 'Gemini' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using google colab I have installed all the dependencies and tried to restart the runtime after this but it is still the same issue.

Run !pip freeze to show your dependencies and their version. You may have an old package installed.
This works for me:
$ pip install llama-index-llms-gemini llama-index google-generativeai

$ pip freeze |egrep "llama.*(core|gemini)"
llama-index-core==0.11.2
llama-index-llms-gemini==0.3.4

$ python
>>> from llama_index.llms.gemini import Gemini
>>> resp = Gemini().complete("Write a poem about a magic backpack")
>>> print(resp)
A backpack worn, a simple thing,
...

To pip-install a precise version, use this syntax: pip install llama-index-llms-gemini==0.3.4

There is one more issue now after running this command
from llama_index.llms.gemini import Gemini
from python interpreter it gives another warning
from openai.openai_object import OpenAIObject ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.openai_object'
